# Dubai airport transfer between Terminal 3 and Terminal 2

Tags: transit, dubai

I have booked a ticket with Emirates from France to Nepal (Kathmandu). The first flight is from France to Dubai Terminal 3, and the second with FlyDubai Terminal 2 to Kathmandu (KTM). I have bought the 2 flights with Emirates.

They told me luggage will be automatically transferred to KTM. I have less than 2h30 between arrival and departure. I read different posts about transfers between the 2 terminals: trains? bus? road service provided by Emirates?

Can someone provide me detailed information? I suppose the best is to go to the transfer desk and ask at the desk... but if you can help, it will be nice.

Answer (score 2):

There is a transfer bus provided for transfer between Terminals 2 and 3, both ways - the transfer is advertised to take around 40 minutes, but usually completes in less than that.

Having just transited Dubai Terminal 3 in the past 2 weeks, I can assure you that there is ample signage for the Terminal 2 bus transfer, and there are many many manned help points where you can be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: One official source is [flydubai](https://www.flydubai.com/en/destinations/flydubai-operations-dxb-terminal-3).